# is there an analytical proof that vega-neutral also provides (gamma & theta) neutral?

Tags: black-scholes, greeks, gamma, vega, theta

I've read an answer [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/3547) that say  if your security has vega, then it has gamma and theta.

is there an analytical proof that vega-neutral also provides (gamma & theta) neutral?

Answer (score 5):

if you have a portfolio of calls and puts with the same maturity then your portfolio is gamma neutral if and only if it is vega neutral.

The reasons is that the BS gamma divided by the BS vega is a function of $S$ and $T$ that does not vary with $K.$ So if you construct a linear combination that has zero gamma then the vega is zero too, and vice versa.

Comment: Do you have the analytical explanation (formula) for vega neutral is also gamma neutral?

Comment: P.S: I already know the analytical explanation for gamma neutral also give theta neutral. I get that analytical explanation from the Timothy falcon book (basic black scholes).

Comment: @TidyStar: For the Black-Scholes model, look up the expressions for vega and gamma and see how similar they are and you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your hypothesis is correct.
If you have a very short dated ATM option, then your option will have close to infinite gamma but close to 0 vega. So this short dated ATM option is vega neutral but definitely not gamma neutral.

Comment: I think you're wrong. It's not about gamma value vs vega value. I'm talking about vega-neutral position is also provide gamma-neutral (and I'm asking the analytical/scientific explanation behind it).

Comment: What is the difference between a position with vega value of 0 and being vega neutral?

Comment: Close to 0 vega (the vega value always be infinitesimal and will not be 0 value, unless the option expire) is not the same thing as vega neutral. If you make trade position to eliminate that close to 0 vega value, that trade position also automatically eliminate gamma & theta.

Comment: Interestingly if the option expire (t=0) the value is not 0 vega & infite gamma. The correct value for both vega & gamma is indeterminate.

Comment: fair point. i ran the following in the black scholes pricer.                           S = 100
T = 0.00001
sig = 0.2
K = 100
r = 0.01

%short term option
gammaShort = blsgamma(S, K, r, T, sig)%6.3078
vegaShort = blsvega(S, K, r, T, sig)%0.1262

%long term option
T2 = 3
gammaLong = blsgamma(S, K, r, T2, sig)  %0.0111
vegaLong = blsvega(S, K, r, T2, sig) %66.857

%ratio to kill all portfolio vega
ratio = vegaShort/vegaLong %0.0019

%buy short term option, sell long term option
portfolioVega =vegaShort - ratio*vegaLong %this will be 0
portfolioGamma = gammaShort - ratio*gammaLong %this is 6.3078

Comment: sorry for the horrible formatting in my comment above. Don't know how to properly format in this comment box. Basically i priced a ratio calendar spread with a flat vol surface. My pricer gives me 0 vega for the spread and positive gamma. Or am I mis interpreting your statement.

Comment: I think there's only one valid implied volatility at the same time for an option (with same maturity) unless it has volatility skew/smile which violate Black-Scholes assumption about the market being in the normal distribution. If this happens, the BS model calculation (including the greeks) will also be invalid.

Comment: I don't know, may be you calculate it wrong. I get the same result if implied volatility is same. The ratio (division) between vega value with different strike are exactly same with the ratio of gamma value with different strike.

Comment: Yes I agree with the Skew/Smile comment.

Comment: It seems that in your calc you vary the strike. Could you try to calc with fixed strike but 2 different **dates**? i.e. a **calendar spread**. I ran with the following parameters: S =100, K = 100, r =0.01, sig = 0.2, T = 3 (years) and then I ran with T = 0.00001 (extremely short dated). I hedged the vega of the short dated call with the vega of the long dated.

Comment: If the maturity is different, that will be 2 options with different T & implied vol. In that case, you only can hedge if you convert the implied vol value with respective of T (the smaller T will also result in smaller volatility), which is difficult to do (non-linear calculation). And also if the long dated converted sigma (smaller sigma) is not same as short dated sigma, you can't hedge that position.

Comment: Yes 2 different maturities, therefore 2 different options. Agreed so far. Not sure why you are saying you can't hedge the greeks of one option with the greeks of another option. Especially in a black scholes world where the entire vol surface is flat (say 20% for example). Why would there be any conversion of vol be needed? You can add the vega of 2 different options (with same underlying).  Maybe we are talking about different things?  What I mean with vega is the change in price for a parallel shift of entire flat surface.

Comment: Well, I think now I know the explanation to your case. It's because the T is different for both options so the result the call/put value (V) will be different in curviness (even it has the same σ) thus also giving different curviness value for Vega=∂V/∂σ and Gamma=∂V²/∂S². I think in most cases, it's better to analyze the problem analytically than numerically.

Comment: excellent. then we agree on all the above. Thanks.